Problems with updating colorbar with matplotlib.Slider listener in Jupyter
The problem that I am having is during updating the colorbar of an plt.imshow plot. Here's the code I will try to break it down and to explain some stuff in it afterwards.

For the first cell in Jupyter, I have the functions, the imports and the input parameters:

# Imports ##############################################################
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from scipy.ndimage import label, find_objects
# Functions ############################################################
def intensity_distribution(r, z, PMax, w0, zR):
    wZ = w0 * np.sqrt(1 + (z / zR)**2)  # beam radius at z (Gaussian beam spreading)
    I0 = 2 * PMax / (np.pi * wZ**2) # peak intensity at radius wZ
    return I0 * np.exp(-2 * r**2 / wZ**2), wZ  # Gaussian intensity distribution, beam radius
def get_circle_ROI(I, r, threshold):
    ROI = (I > threshold).astype("uint8")  # binary mask for regions above the threshold
    labels, features = label(ROI) # label connected regions
    slices = find_objects(labels) # get bounding box slices for labeled regions
    xSlice, ySlice = slices[0] # extract x and y slices of the largest feature
    ROIHeight = (xSlice.stop - xSlice.start) * (r[1] - r[0]) * 1e6 # convert height to micrometers
    ROIWidth = (ySlice.stop - ySlice.start) * (r[1] - r[0]) * 1e6 # convert width to micrometers
    cx = (ySlice.start + ySlice.stop) // 2 # x-coordinate of the center
    cy = (xSlice.start + xSlice.stop) // 2 # y-coordinate of the center
    centre = (r[cy] * 1e6, r[cx] * 1e6) # convert center coordinates to micrometers
    radius = min(ROIWidth, ROIHeight) / 2 # radius is the smaller dimension's half-width
    return centre, radius
def update_plot(PMax, zOffset):
    """Update the heatmap based on new parameters."""
    global colorbar
    # Calculate intensity distribution at given z offset
    I, wZ = intensity_distribution(np.sqrt(R**2 + Z**2), zOffset, PMax, BEAM_RADIUS_AT_FOCUS, zR)
    I /= 1e6  # convert intensity from W/m² to W/mm²
    I += 0.01  # small offset for better visualization contrast
    max_intensity = I.max()  # maximum intensity in the current distribution
    # Calculate the on-axis peak intensity at focus in W/mm²
    I0 = (2 * PMax) / (np.pi * BEAM_RADIUS_AT_FOCUS**2)  # peak intensity in W/m² at z = 0
    I0 /= 1e6  # convert peak intensity to W/mm²
    # Calculate the Full Width at Half Maximum (FWHM) in micrometers
    centre, fwhm = get_circle_ROI(I, r, max_intensity / 2)
    _, tenth = get_circle_ROI(I, r, max_intensity / 10)
    # Clear and update plot
    ax.clear()  # clear current axes
    # Display the updated intensity distribution as a heatmap
    im = ax.imshow(I, extent=[r[0]*1e6, r[-1]*1e6, r[0]*1e6, r[-1]*1e6], norm=colors.LogNorm(vmax=14000))
    ax.set_xlabel("x (μm)")  # label for x-axis
    ax.set_ylabel("y (μm)")  # label for y-axis
    # Add plot title with z offset, FWHM, and max intensity in W/mm²
    ax.set_title(f"FWHM = {fwhm:.1f} μm\n"
                 f"Radius at 10% of total power = {tenth:.2f} μm\n"
                 f"Max power = {I.max():.2f} W/mm²",
                 loc="left")
    # Draw a circle representing the FWHM boundary
    cirlcefwhm = plt.Circle(centre, fwhm, color='white', fill=False, linestyle='--', linewidth=2, label="FWHM")
    cirlce10 = plt.Circle(centre, tenth, color='white', fill=False, linestyle='--', linewidth=2, label="10% of I$_max$")
    ax.add_patch(cirlcefwhm)  # add the FWHM circle to the plot
    ax.add_patch(cirlce10)  # add the circle where power is 10% of max
    #### Problematic starts here ####
    if colorbar is not None:   # if colorbar already exists, remove it
        colorbar.remove()
    colorbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, label="Intensity (W/mm²)")  # create new colorbar in W/mm²
    fig.draw_without_rendering() # redraw based on the recommendation of matplotlib instead of colorbar.draw_all()
    fig.canvas.draw()  # redraw figure to reflect updates
    #### Problematic ends here ####
def sliders_on_changed(val):
    ''' Slider update function '''
    power = power_slider.val * MAX_LASER_POWER / 100  # calculate current power level in watts
    z_offset = z_offset_slider.val / 1000 # convert slider z offset from mm to meters
    update_plot(power, z_offset) # update the plot with new parameters
# Inputs ###############################################################
WAVELENGTH = 10.6e-6  # wavelength in meters
MAX_LASER_POWER = 80  # max laser power in watts
BEAM_WIDTH_AT_FOCUS = 120e-6  # beam width at focus in meters
BEAM_RADIUS_AT_FOCUS = BEAM_WIDTH_AT_FOCUS / 2  # beam radius at focus in meters
zR = np.pi * BEAM_RADIUS_AT_FOCUS**2 / WAVELENGTH  # Rayleigh range in meters
gridSize = 100 # resolution
r = np.linspace(-500e-6, 500e-6, gridSize)  # range for spatial coordinates in meters
R, Z = np.meshgrid(r, r) # create grid for spatial coordinates
colorbar = None # init colorbar

The problematic part would be this one:
#### Problematic starts here ####
if colorbar is not None:   # if colorbar already exists, remove it
    colorbar.remove()
colorbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, label="Intensity (W/mm²)")  # create new colorbar in W/mm²
fig.draw_without_rendering() # redraw based on the recommendation of matplotlib instead of colorbar.draw_all()
fig.canvas.draw()  # redraw figure to reflect updates
#### Problematic ends here ####

Am not so sure why it is not working. What happens is that the colorbar appears for the first update and then dissapears after a change in the Z-offset or the power percentage. Basically after a change in any of the values.

The second cell of the jupyter notebook has the call for the functions:

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.35)  # leave space for sliders
update_plot(50, 0)
ax_power = plt.axes([0.25, 0.2, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor = "lightgray")
ax_z_offset = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor = "lightgray")
power_slider = Slider(ax_power, 'Power (%)', 0.1, 100, valinit=50)
z_offset_slider = Slider(ax_z_offset, 'Z-Offset (mm)', 0, 5.0, valinit=0)
power_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)
z_offset_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)

Running this will get you to a UI that looks like this:

And then when I move any of the sliders the colorbar disappears:

The updating of the colorbar seems to be a common problem, I saw a lot of stackoverflow questions about it, I even answered one once.
The solution however is not really working with the slider listeners.
P.S.: Changing the backend does not really help. However, using %matplotlib qt revealed a traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 309, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\widgets.py", line 603, in <lambda>
    return self._observers.connect('changed', lambda val: func(val))
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_26252\2170461726.py", line 66, in sliders_on_changed
    update_plot(power, z_offset) # update the plot with new parameters
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_26252\2170461726.py", line 57, in update_plot
    colorbar.remove()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 1041, in remove
    self.ax.remove()
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 242, in remove
    self._remove_method(self)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 944, in delaxes
    self._axstack.remove(ax)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 92, in remove
    self._axes.pop(a)
KeyError: <Axes: label='<colorbar>', ylabel='Intensity (W/mm²)'>

Some stuff that I tried:

There is a method for colorbar called draw_all()
Matplotlib also suggests using fig.draw_without_rendering()
My own solution
Setting the limits of colorbar without deleting the colorbar

Can someone please help me in figuring out what's wrong? I understand ofc that the code is quite long, I can shorten it to a simple example if necessary.

I am using

Jupyter 6.5.4
Matplotlib 3.7.2


You'd have to specify what versions of Jupyter software you are using. For example, %matplotlib notebook is not what I'd be using with modern tech that I wanted to be interactive with ipywidgets and matplotlib. See here for how you should be using current approaches with current tech. (You need to install ipympl and make sure it works.) But maybe you aren't using the current stuff and so that is why it somewhat works? See the issue? You aren't providing related information in your post and treating 'Jupyter' all as the same.

@Wayne thanks for the comment, indeed I am using an older distribution of anaconda. I'll include the versions in the question. I would appreciate a solution with newer anaconda distributions or other backends all the same:D

I gave you a large part of the solution with newer Anaconda Distributions. To spell it out: No more %matplotlib notebook. You install ipympl and use %matplotlib ipympl. The package ipympl requires special additional handling when installing, for example you need a hard refresh of any browser page where you were using Jupyter prior to installation to clear out and propagate the many changes it makes. Fortunately, newer Anaconda Distributions include ipympl already installed and so when using those it should just work right away without worrying about all that. But for your code...

@Wayne I'm not looking to remediate your code for you to turn around and say you got it working with JupyterLab 2 or Notebook 6.5 and don't need that. Am not sure why you got this impression, as I said, a solution in another version is highly welcome. P.S: no need for the imperative tone ;)

Adding in code from 'V2.0' over there and additional code, I was able to get something running where ipympl is installed that seemed to recreate what you are saying happens. It would have been much nicer to follow the guide to How do I ask a good question? and include a fully working minimal reproducible example. Especially with a complex post like this. Anyway the slider goes away. Then if I remove ...

The removal line, I get tons of colorbars when I slide, like you say. I would suggest using interact(). But because the provided code is disjointed and not, as such an actual working MRE, it is painful to develop on it.

@Wayne thanks for the help, i'll try with interact tomorrow. Btw, the question has everything for an MRE. There are two cells, as mentioned in the question.

Well maybe then it is because Python 3.10 is the oldest I am able to easily scrounge up, but I doubt it since there is no im defined and time isn't imported. -- if you wanted to see what I mean: Start a new session and paste in your provided code. (You can go here and launch a session and try it to see.)  I had to then go get the im where I referenced and the code there caused further issues. I did do them as two cells but because you need interactivity, it would be easier as one cell. (You can use ...

 here to start a session when you want to try with ipympl in a more current background. That was where I tried initially but because you insisted it was an MRE, I tried some older Python, too. Just not back as far back as 3.7 yet.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I managed to solve this problem on my old version by using the following lines to update the colormap:
if colorbar is not None: # if colorbar already exists, update it
    colorbar.mappable.set_clim(vmax=max_intensity)
else:    
    colorbar = plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, label="Intensity (W/mm²)") # create new colorbar in W/mm²

Updating Anaconda was not needed in this case. The code above works both for the old version and the old version (under the %matplotlib qt backend)
Proof:


The advice about using ipympl lead to a RuntimeError under a clean new anaconda installation. So, really no need for that.

Using interact() does not solve anything.

Here is a minimal example of using interact to update the colorbar: click here and the session will start. When the session begins run the cell there. (The boring static version of the notebook you'll see there is here.

Thanks for the code and for your time, I tried it out, it works as you said. I'll look to update my anaconda version with all the necessary packages to reproduce your simple solution in the future. For now, using  colorbar.mappable.set_clim(vmax=max_intensity) seems to work

Yes, no rush for you to update. At this point, I'm mostly adding that to address others not stuck with your old Python and using current, working tech. This was why I also wanted to know version numbers early on. With the many changes in the last few years, things are different and that is where newcomers who may end up here in a few weeks most likely need to start.
